# google drive modified date give wrong time

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

i am try to create an android app in which use google drive to store a file. now want to detect change in a same file by any device.for detect change in a file try to get modified time of file using the below code(using new google drive api for android) https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, fileId);
Metadata fmd = file.getMetadata(mGoogleApiClient).await().getMetadata();
Log.e("modified date",""+fmd.getModifiedDate());
```

but its give modeified time always wrong.. its not return the modified time when other device(using same app) modify the same file. 
is there any other way to detect change in file??? thanx

i am also use below code but no luck

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, fileId);
file.getMetadata(mGoogleApiClient).addResultCallback(new DemoClassForHandleCallBack());

public class DemoClassForHandleCallBack implements OnMetadataRetrievedCallback{

    @Override
    public void onMetadataRetrieved(MetadataResult result) {
        boolean isSuccess = result.getStatus().isSuccess();
            Log.i("is success",""+isSuccess);
        Metadata fmd = result.getMetadata();
        Log.e("modified date",""+fmd.getModifiedDate());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check whether the metadata is being fetched successfully or not (while using the ResultCallback)?

Comment: yes i checked it and it always return success (Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}) thnx for help

Comment: Are you calling the getFile from the onConnected method?

Comment: no, i am doing this after get callBack from ConnectionCallbacks but not in onConnected() method, i think its not issue with onConnected bcus if i want to upload the file its work fine just prob with getModifiedDate()

Comment: Just try it in the onConnected() method

Comment: but i want to use getModifiedDate() method more than once while onConnected() called only once when the first time connection created

Comment: i am also try it onConnected() but its not give latest time of modification...

Comment: Just a wrinkle...with the new API you do not necessarily read/write to the servers.  Enabled airplane mode on my phone, my app is still writing and reading those files back.  The data is cached pending later upload.  I bet that's likely to affect modification dates.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that as of now, the Google Drive seems to have a bug in reporting "last modified" date even when viewed from Chrome on a desktop computer...

Comment: I'm having almost the exact same issue.  @nikhil, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but I just solved this problem myself.

It turns out that the metadata is stale/cached, UNLESS you first OPEN the file in question.

Thus, the working code is as follows:

```
DriveFile file;

// Trick Google Drive into fetching the remote file
// which has the latest metadata
file.open( getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();

DriveResource.MetadataResult result = file.getMetadata(getGoogleApiClient()).await();
Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();

// Get the modified date
metadata.getModifiedDate();
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I'm also observing similar behavior. I wasn't reading in the file unless the modified date changed, which resulted in only fetching the new file if I restarted the entire process. After removing the check (and fetching everytime), everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use modified date to detect changes. You should look for changes to etag.

Comment: but there is nothing like etag in new Google drive android api

Comment: My apologies. Because the question tags include google-drive-sdk I hadn't realised you were referring to the new android API. The new API is missing a lot of the full Drive metadata. You'll simply need to wait for the API to mature, or go back to using conventional Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make use of the `onMetadataRetrieved(MetadataResult result)` API? Doesn't seem so from your code. You need to call the `getMetaData()` method from inside the `onMetadaRetrieved` function.

Comment: Could you please paste this code in the answer? Its hard to read here.